# Umbraco 5: site search

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, razor, umbraco, umbraco5

Is there a viable way to search an Umbraco 5 site? I've read a lot on XLST search, but nothing using MVC3. It also seems that Examine is coming a little bit buggy, as even the backoffice has lost the search box that was present in v4. Any ideas?

Comment: I was actually working on a little something last night; its not going to be perfect (not Google) but a decent start. Watch this space, as I'll try to make a package out of it soon.

Comment: Great, I'll keep an eye!

Comment: Unfortunately package support stumped progress for me initially, but now that U5 has been officially abandoned that's an even bigger hurdle. I might still do what I was going to do but for 4.7.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know Umbraco V5 is retire; you can try 4.x and do the above with user controls that do search logic using umbraco node factory.

Hope you get my views.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a very basic search, it might not be best way but it gives the results I need.

```
var results = Hive.QueryContent().OfRevisionType(FixedStatusTypes.Published).ToList().Where(c => c.AllAncestorIds().Any() && c.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query.ToLowerInvariant()) && c.Attribute<bool>("excludeFromSearch") == false).ToList();
```

`OfRevisionType(FixedStatusTypes.Published)` returns published pages
`c.AllAncestorIds().Any()` stops deleted items being returned

Comment: And how do you feed the query to Hive? Also, how would you render the list in a view? Just @results?